# Second .xml file not opening on android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am doing android app to change the values of celcsius to fahrenheit and vice-versa. But when opening the second xml page, it stop working.

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGO"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="147dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewHello"
    android:text="@string/button1_str" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFarh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewHello"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/FarhTextStr" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextCelc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextFarh"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextFarh"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/CelcTextStr" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

new_page.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBACK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="87dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="@string/button2_str" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonChangeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonBACK"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonBACK"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonBACK"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextCelc2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonChangeText"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/CelcTextStr" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFarh2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonChangeText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextCelc2"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/FarhTextStr" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btGo;

private static final String FAHR_VALUE = "FAHR_VALUE";
private static final String CELC_VALUE = "CELC_VALUE";

EditText FahrET;
EditText CelcET;

private double fahrValue;
private double celcValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        fahrValue = 0.0;
        celcValue = 0.0;
    }
    else{
        fahrValue = savedInstanceState.getDouble(FAHR_VALUE);
        celcValue = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CELC_VALUE);
    }

    FahrET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFarh);
    CelcET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCelc);

    FahrET.addTextChangedListener(changeValueListener);

    updateFinalValue();

    btGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGO);
    btGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewPage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private TextWatcher changeValueListener = new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            fahrValue = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            fahrValue = 0.0;
        }

        updateFinalValue();

    }

};

private void updateFinalValue(){

    double finalResult = (((fahrValue - 32) * 5) / 9);

    CelcET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalResult));
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putDouble(FAHR_VALUE, fahrValue);
    outState.putDouble(CELC_VALUE, celcValue);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

NewPage.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewPage extends Activity {

TextView Hello;

private static final String FAHR_VALUE2 = "FAHR_VALUE2";
private static final String CELC_VALUE2 = "CELC_VALUE2";

private double celcValue2;
private double fahrValue2;

EditText newCelcET;
EditText newFahrET;


Button btBack;
Button chText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_page);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        celcValue2 = 0.0;
        fahrValue2 = 0.0;

    }
    else{
        celcValue2 = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CELC_VALUE2);
        fahrValue2 = savedInstanceState.getDouble(FAHR_VALUE2);
    }

    newCelcET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCelc2);
    newFahrET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFarh2);

    newFahrET.addTextChangedListener(changeValueListenerTwo);



    Hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHello);

    btBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBACK);
    btBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });
    chText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChangeText);
    chText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Hello.setText("It Worked!!!");
        }
    });

    FinalValue2();

}

private TextWatcher changeValueListenerTwo = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)    

    {   // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            fahrValue2 = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            fahrValue2 = 0.0;
        }

        FinalValue2();
    }
};

private void FinalValue2(){
    double finalResult2 = (((celcValue2 * 9) / 5) + 32);

    newFahrET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalResult2));
}


protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putDouble(FAHR_VALUE2, fahrValue2);
    outState.putDouble(CELC_VALUE2, celcValue2);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I've done some testing and I saw that the error occurs when I use the `FinalValue2` function.

This are the erros:

```
01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051): java.lang.StackOverflowError

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:125)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.util.Formatter.transform_f(Formatter.java:2245)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.util.Formatter.transformFromFloat(Formatter.java:2097)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1496)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1101)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1062)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1031)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2177)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2151)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.FinalValue2(NewPage.java:110)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.access$1(NewPage.java:107)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage$1.afterTextChanged(NewPage.java:103
)
01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6330)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2737)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.FinalValue2(NewPage.java:110)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.access$1(NewPage.java:107)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage$1.afterTextChanged(NewPage.java:103)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6330)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2737)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.FinalValue2(NewPage.java:110)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.access$1(NewPage.java:107)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage$1.afterTextChanged(NewPage.java:103)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6330)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2737)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.FinalValue2(NewPage.java:110)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.access$1(NewPage.java:107)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage$1.afterTextChanged(NewPage.java:103)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6330)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2737)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.FinalValue2(NewPage.java:110)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.access$1(NewPage.java:107)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage$1.afterTextChanged(NewPage.java:103)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6330)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2737)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.FinalValue2(NewPage.java:110)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.access$1(NewPage.java:107)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage$1.afterTextChanged(NewPage.java:103)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6330)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2737)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.FinalValue2(NewPage.java:110)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.access$1(NewPage.java:107)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage$1.afterTextChanged(NewPage.java:103)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6330)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2737)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2598)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.NewPage.FinalValue2(NewPage.java:110)

01-04 15:11:34.323: E/AndroidRuntime(2051):     at com.luisoms.doubletest.N
```

I've done a lot trying to fix the TextWatcher, but it appears that it's not the problem, but I just can't find it

Comment: Could you post the error message ?

Comment: You should name your methods from lowercase letter.
It is standard Java convention.

Comment: I've tried this already, it didn't worked anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TextWatcher` changes the text it is monitoring, triggering another call to the watcher, changing the text it is monitoring, triggering another call to the watcher, ... and so on until there's no more stack to call any further methods.

One way to fix it is to set a boolean flag in the class so that you can distinguish between user-originated edits and code-originated edits:

```
boolean mIsInTextWatcher = false;

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (mIsInTextWatcher)
        return;
    mIsInTextWatcher = true;

    // do whatever you do, possibly modifying the text

    mIsInTextWatcher = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm very new at this, so I didn't quite understand how this would work

Comment: Don't you have any adea that's not related to the TextWatcher?

Comment: That's what the stacktrace says.

Comment: but I did exactly what you said and it didn't worked. I have to put this only on the second .java right?